# Javascript super method not found error on class inheritance

Tags: javascript, class

Consider the following code:

```js
class Parent {
  constructor(name) {
    this.name = name;
  }

  whoAmI = data => {
    console.log("Parent whoAmI called. Parent name: " + this.name);
    console.log(data);
  };
}

class Child extends Parent {
  constructor(childName, parentName) {
    this.name = childName;
    super(parentName);
  }

  whoAmI = data => {
    console.log("Child whoAmI called. Parent name: " + this.name);
    super.whoAmI(data);
  };
}

let child = new Child("Dad", "Son");
child.whoAmI("Hello!");
```

I'm getting the following error on my `node` environment:

```
return _get((_thisSuper = _assertThisInitialized(_this), _getPrototypeOf(Parent.prototype)), "whoAmI", _thisSuper).call(_thisSuper, data);
                                                                                                                                           ^

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'call')
```

As the error says, `super.whoAmI` is not being found, but I've initialized the parent class... no idea of what's wrong...

What is the correct way to override and call the `super.whoAmI` method?

Comment: You can't call `super` if you're not extending another class.

Comment: Ops... paste problem... fixing.... fixed... sorry

Comment: Running your code now, gives me the following error: "ReferenceError: Must call super constructor in derived class before accessing 'this' or returning from derived constructor". In other words, you can't call `this.name = childName` before `super(parentName)`.  Also you can't call `super` from an arrow function. Use the regular `whoAmI(data) { ... }` syntax.

Answer (score 3):

1. You should call `super` first before using `this` in a constructor. This is because `this` should be constructed from top to bottom in a class hierarchy to avoid ambiguity I guess.
2. You cannot use `super` with a OWN property of an object as you did with `whoAmI()`. a `super`'s method should be in the class' prototype and done as a class method through `method(){}` syntax. Everything assigned as a property `prop = ...` goes as an own property of the instance, not of its prototype.
3. You cannot use `this.name = childName` since you have only one `this` across all classes involved. You should use a private property `this.#name` that is unique per class.
4. You should swap `Son` and `Dad` when constructing, since parameters don't match arguments' order.
5. A probable copy-paste error: rather log own class names, than `Parent` in both cases.

```js
class Parent {
  #name;
  constructor(name) {
    this.#name = name;
  }

  whoAmI( data) {
    console.log("Parent whoAmI called. My name: " + this.#name);
    console.log(data);
  };
}

class Child extends Parent {
  #name;
  constructor(childName, parentName) {
    super(parentName);
    this.#name = childName;
  }

  whoAmI = data => {
    console.log("Child whoAmI called. My name: " + this.#name);
    super.whoAmI(data);
  };
}

let child = new Child("Son", "Dad");
child.whoAmI("Hello!");
```